# Index/Match to return a list of results matching criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I have an array of values (hours) that are assigned to jobs for every day of the month.

I would like to build a schedule for the day - a list of job numbers that need to be done today.

@Scott Craner helped to build the reverse tool - it returns a date for a job in question.

[image: search jobs]

```
=INDEX(B2:E2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(INDEX(B3:E9,MATCH(G3,A3:A9,),)<>"",),0))
```

Comment: Any priority between jobs? Or are they all equal? Should shortest be done first or longest?

Comment: we need them be listed for the searched day in the same order they are listed in the main schedule. I simplified the actual spreadsheet. The actual job numbers are complicated and has their name convention. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on has the new dynamic array formula Filter put this in H4 and Excel will spill down the results:

```
=FILTER(A3:A9,INDEX(B3:E9,,MATCH(H2,B2:E2,0))<>"")
```

If not then we need to get a little more creative.  Put this in H4 and copy down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$3:$A$9)/(INDEX($B$3:$E$9,,MATCH($H$2,$B$2:$E$2,0))<>""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Comment: =FILTER formula - my excel 2013 doesn't recognize this function: "That function isn't valid"

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX formula error says "The formula is missing an opening and closing parenthesis".. I found the missing bracket, added: "You've entered too few arguments for this function". Thanks.

Comment: I edited it adding the issue, make sure you refresh the page. and try the formula again.

Comment: The second formula worked like a charm! The Filter formula - same error. When I type =filter.. excel is letting me select only FILTERXML function as the only available. Thank you.

Comment: @PavloKobzar that is why I gave two.  the first only works if you have Office 365

Comment: I'm trying to adapt this formula to a real array. I can mostly understand everything except the last ROW(A1). how do I use that part for any other chart? in my above example it will return 1, where the cell A1 is. in my real chart row 1 has the dates when jobs are scheduled. Should I add an empty row on top and let ROW(A1) use it?

Comment: no, it is just a counter,  leave it as `ROW(A1)` no matter where it is put or where the data is.